# How to denote sum over partitions?

Tags: notation, integer-partitions, article-writing

How does one denote a sum of partitions of an integer when writing an article? For example, I have a formula regarding an integer-valued variable (say q=5), and I need to write an expression of the form:

$$\sum_{p\in P(q)}$$

where $P(q)$ is the set of all partitions of $q$ (for example $\{1+1+1+1+1,1+1+1+2,1+2+2,1+1+3,2+3,4+1,5\}$) and $p$ is an element of the set, a particular partition. Then inside the summand, I need to refer to both the size of the partition (which I suppose I could denote $|p|$) and the contents of the partition. Is there any standard way of doing this?

Comment: I'm guessing there's no standard way of doing it, but perhaps writing (under the $\sum$) this: $p_1+\dotsb+p_k=q$ would work? $k$ would be the size of the partition, $p_1$ would be the smallest element of the partition, etc. (Of course, should you do this, make sure you explain everything in the text.) Like this: $\displaystyle\sum_{p_1+\dotsb+p_k=q}\operatorname{stuff}(\text{things})$

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger But then the order of $p$ matters if we wrote $p_1+\cdots+p_k=n$. am I right?

Comment: @M.K How about $$\sum_{\substack{p_1+\dotsb+p_k=q\\p_1<\dotsb<p_k}}$$

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I think this is nice because it keeps one and eliminates all other orders.

Comment: @M.K I should have written $\le$, not $<$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for sums over structures rather than simple integer ranges you have a few options:

1. Use notation indicating the structure. Here, for example, you could follow George Andrews in using $\lambda \vdash n$ to denote that $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$, and write

   > $$\sum_{\lambda\, \vdash \, n}f(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n, n)$$

   NB I've used `\,` for spacing in the subscript.
2. As a variant on the previous point, express the constraint algebraically, as suggested in the comments:

   > $$\sum_{\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_k = n} f(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k,n)$$
3. Use notation indicating the bound variables and express the constraint in text separately. E.g.

   > $$\sum_{\lambda_1,\,\ldots,\,\lambda_n} f(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n,n)$$ where the sum is over the partitions of $n$

Since the purpose of mathematical writing is communication, I would favour a combination of 1 and 3 (where possible) for most audiences:

> $$\sum_{\lambda\, \vdash \, n}f(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n, n)$$ where the sum is over the partitions of $n$

Comment: What do I do if I want to refer to the number of times a certain integer appears in the partition within $f$? Say, for example, we have the partition $13=5+2+2+2+1+1$ and I want to refer for each integer in the partition $1,2,5$ the respective number of times that it appears $2,3,1$. How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: @ruadan, it depends. If you're just referring to frequencies and total then you can use the standard notation for the frequency representation and subscript the sum with $(1^{a_1}2^{a_2}\ldots)\vdash n$. If you're referring to both parts and frequencies you need to consider whether to subscript as $\lambda = (1^{a_1}2^{a_2}\ldots)\vdash n$ or just to explain in the accompanying text how the $\lambda_i$ relate to the $a_j$.