# Expressing a sum over the sizes of the parts of every partition of n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, integer-partitions

Let $(a_1^{r_1},\ldots,a_{p}^{r_{p}})\vdash n$ be the multiplicity representation of an integer partition of *n*. Each $a_{i}$ is a ***part*** of the partition and $r_{i}$ is its corresponding ***size***. We exclude sizes of 0. Thus, for example, $(1^{4},3^{2},6^{1})$ is the multiplicity representation of the partition $(1,1,1,1,3,3,6)$ of 16. Consider the following sum which sums over *every* partition of *n* (so *p* is not constant – *f* is merely a function over the multiset of sizes for each partition)...

$$ \sum_{(a_1^{r_1},\ldots,a_{p}^{r_{p}}) \vdash n} f(r_1,...,r_p)$$

Since the summand only refers to the sizes $r_{i}$ of the parts and does not refer to the parts $a_{i}$ themselves, this seems like an inefficient way of expressing and computing the sum.

Can you recommend a better, more efficient way of expressing such a sum? In particular, can you recommend a sum where what is being summed over does not refer to the parts of the partitions?

Note: Summing over the solutions to the corresponding Diophantine equation still refers to the parts.

Comment: How would you represent the partition $(1,1,2,4,4,5)$? Would that be $(1^2,2^1,4^4,5^1)$ or $(1^2,2^1,3^0,4^2,5^1)$? Are you considering fixed $p$, or can $p$ vary?

Comment: $(1,1,2,4,4,5)$ is represented as $(1^{2},2^{1},4^{2},5^{1})$ in the multiplicity representation. *p* must vary, if the sum is to be over all partitions of *n*, which is intended.

Comment: But you've written $f$ is a function of $p$ variables. So how do you account for varying $p$?

Comment: Yes, this is no different from how the summand can be a function of each partition when summing over all partitions of n, even though the sizes and parts of each partition is different. For example, [see answer 1 here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088046/how-to-denote-sum-over-partitions). The number of arguments of *f* do change, but it isn't problematic.

Comment: I mean you could write down functions $h_1,h_2,\dots$ such that $h_i(\lambda)=r_i$, and a function $p$ such that $p(\lambda)$ is the number of distinct parts of $\lambda$ and then write $\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} f(h_1(\lambda), h_2(\lambda),\dots, h_{p(\lambda)}(\lambda))$.